# Modify an existing scrapy spider the website implemented a captcha - how to get an image that pops up for decode and continue?

Tags: python, scrapy, captcha, web-crawler

I have an existing scrapy spider that scrapes a public records site and the spider works great but they added a captcha popup that broke the spider (original programmer is unavailable).

I'm trying to see how to modify the existing spider to handle this.

for example from:

http://publicindex.sccourts.org/mccormick/publicindex/

if I click on the Accept button a captcha form now pops up.

I can from my browser right click and save the image, and in fact I can decode it via one of the decaptcha apis floating out there.  but I'm very new to scrapy so could use some help in seeing how to extract the image and handle it.

could use some help :)

Comment: *" Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results."*

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the image of captcha using xpath like

hxs.select("//div[@class='captcha']/img[@src]")

and then handle it.

Above is example of HtmlXPathSelector , you can use others also.

For more information http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.18/topics/selectors.html